# Would this question be on-topic here?

Tags: discussion, questions

The question is:

How can I speed-read while walking fast?

I want to spend the time when I walk from m office to home, reading. So, are there any ways I can learn how to speed-read while walking fast?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would likely be closed as *off topic.*

> **"Mind hacks" are off topic** — Questions dealing with personal productivity and self-improvement tips, memorization and learning techniques, etc. are outside the scope of this site.

You may want to have a look at [Personal Productivity](https://productivity.stackexchange.com/) to see if your question is on topic there.

Comment: Thank you for answering Robert.  Would post in the PP SE!